# How to use multiple models inside service in Angular / Ionic app?

Tags: angular, typescript

In my Angular / Ionic app, I am trying to create 2 models below (Conversation & Message), & use them inside my Conversations Service.

When users log in, they should see a list of previous conversations they have had with mechanics (also users but with a different *userType*).

When they click on a Conversation, they are brought to the Conversation_Detail screen which shows all the messages that are part of that conversation.

On Conversation_Detail, users & mechanics can send new messages. These new messages will be added to the existing Conversation.

Here are the models I have:

`conversation.model.ts`

```
export class Conversation {
    constructor(
        public id: string,
        public userId: string,
        public mechanicId: string,
        public messages: Array<string>,
    ) { }
}
```

`message.model.ts`

```
export class Message {
    constructor(
        public id: string,
        public text: string,
        public userId: string,
        timestamp: string
    ) { }
}
```

As you can see above, I'm trying to connect multiple Messages to one Conversation.

And here is where I'm trying to create a dummy conversation:

`Conversations.service.ts`

```
private _conversations: Conversation[] = [
    new Conversation('c1', 'abc1', 'def2', ['Hi', 'What is your issue?'])
  ];
```

Can someone please tell me how I can correctly link Conversations & Messages so that I can use them in the Conversations Service?

Comment: an idea would be using this messages array in constructor for keeping the messages ids, this way you could get the messages when you want.

Comment: or, better, instead of an array of strings, you can save each message directly inside if you use an array of objects. 

like ( ..., messages: Message[])

Comment: Hi @LucasLeandro thanks for your responses. Can you post these changes below in an answer please? Just so I can understand properly what you're suggesting.

Comment: Sure, but before that, please explain me what you want to do with more details? Like, the entire flow. This way we can think about the process and maybe give a more accurate answer

Comment: @LucasLeandro No problem, will update my question with those details, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made an attempt at fixing it, & here is what I've come up with, testing it out at the moment, will update if it's working or not:

`conversations.service.ts`

```
private _conversations: Conversation[] = [
    new Conversation(
      'c1',
      'abc1',
      'def2',
      [new Message('mess1', 'Test message', 'abc1', '01/01/2020')])
  ];
```

`conversation.model.ts`

```
import { Message } from './message.model';

export class Conversation {
    constructor(
        public id: string,
        public userId: string,
        public mechanicId: string,
        public messages: Message[],
    ) { }
}
```

`message.model.ts`

```
export class Message {
    constructor(
        public id: string,
        public text: string,
        public userId: string,
        timestamp: string
    ) { }
}
```

Comment: @LucasLeandro Is this the solution you were thinking of? It works as expected for now, yes. Does this structure meet the requirements I outlined in my question? I.e. Being able to display the messages within each conversation on a Conversation_Detail page?

Comment: Yes! Because, if you have this data in memory, you will be able to access all Messages inside each Conversation, since you initialized the Conversation passing the messages. Just remember, when u recive a new message, you have to put it inside the Messages Array, for the correct Conversation. Can you do it? Maybe you will need a Conversation ID for being able to redirect each message for its correct conversation

Comment: Are you saying when I create a new message, I may need the Conversation ID to link it back to a conversation? If so, all new messages will be created within Conversation_Detail, so I think I would have the Conversation ID in that case

Comment: Depends of your apps flow. If you know witch conversation are you inside, in the moment the message gets created, then you could redirect it directly. If you dont, then this id might be important